# Cordova iOS what is the value for provisioningProfile value for both debug and release

Tags: ios, json, xcode, cordova, provisioning-profile

how do you get ***provisioningProfile*** value for your ***build.json*** file?

I already enrolled the Apple developer program, get all things set (app id, provision etc) but I confused about the value for `provisioningProfile`.

I need to build the XCODE project using cordova. Here is my `build.json` file looks like:

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iOS Development",
            "provisioningProfile": "<WHAT TO INSERT HERE>",
            "developmentTeam": "MY COMPANY",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iOS Distribution",
            "provisioningProfile": "<WHAT TO INSERT HERE>",
            "developmentTeam": "MY COMPANY",
            "packageType": "app-store"
        }
    }
}
```

I already download the provisioning profile files for both `debug` and `release` version. The name of both files looks like this:

**Debug**: `MYPROJECT_Development.mobileprovision`

**Release**: `XC_iOS_MyProject.mobileprovision`

Where is the value to put as the `provisioningProfile`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you open the .mobileprovision file with a text editor, it has an ID field, that should be the value to use

Comment: Hi :D I have tried that, opened the `.mobileprovision` extension file with sublime text but I found no information contained the info you mentioned above :(

Comment: Sublime doesn't display it correctly. Try with TextEdit, then search for `<key>UUID</key><string>your-identifier</string>`

Comment: Hi, yeah it works :D opened it on TextEdit solved the problem, it turns out that the UUID is basically the filename without the `.mobileprovision` extension. thanks man :D